# Fill the "Unpublish on" date field of the Scheduler module depending on list field

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a content type, where I want to give the user only three possibilities to unpublish content: in 1, 3 or 6 months. For the selection of the three options I use a list field. How can I transfer the selected value to the unpublish field?

Answer (score 0):

You'd do better to have a custom module that does a form alter on the unpublish date field itself - converting it from a date/text to a date/select.